# How to set Layout with another class in Java?

Tags: java, gridbaglayout

I'm writing a programm with a complicated TabbedPane, with lots of elements. Since I hit the Byte-limit in one of my classes, I decided to split the class into Initialisation/Button Listeners and the actual GridBagLayout. But now I'm having trouble getting it to work. My Main Class looks like this:

```
public class Main{
JFrame mainFrame = new JFrame("");
JTabbedPane tabpane = new JTabbedPane();
JPanel panelTab1 = new Tab1();
JScrollPane scrollTab2 = new JScrollPane(new Tab2());
JScrollPane scrollTab3 = new JScrollPane(new Tab3());
JPanel panelTab4 = new Tab4();
JMenuBar bar = new MenuBar();


public Main(){
    tabpane.add("Tab1", panelTab1);
    tabpane.add("Tab2", scrollTab2);
    tabpane.add("Tab3", scrollTab3);
    tabpane.add("Tab4", panelTab4);
    mainFrame.getContentPane().add(tabpane);
    mainFrame.setSize(1920,1080);   
    mainFrame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    mainFrame.setVisible(true);     
    mainFrame.validate();
    mainFrame.setJMenuBar(bar);

}



public static void main(String[] args)
{

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            new Main();
        }
    });


}}
```

Tab3 is the culprit so here are the two classes I split.

```
public class Tab3 extends JPanel {
JPanel Annex = new JPanel();
//A Bunch of Labels and Buttons
.
.
.
public Tab3(){
//ActionListeners for the Buttons
this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
this.add(Annex,BorderLayout.WEST);
this.add(Bsp,BorderLayout.EAST);
}}
```

All the GridBagLayout is in the following class:

```
public class Tab3Layout extends Tab3{
    public Tab3Layout(){
        Annex.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints co1 = new GridBagConstraints();
        co1.gridx = 0;
        co1.gridy = 0;
        co1.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;
        co1.weighty = 1.0;
        Annex.add(Annex1, co1);
        //and so on...
        }}
```

Now my question is, how do I get this to work? Right now if I compile, Tab3 is just empty. If everything is in one class it works exactly how I want, but the code is just much too long. Seems to me like I'm missing a line in the Tab3 class, but even after hours of tinkering and searching I have no idea how to solve this. Everything I tried just produced more errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in iheritance. `Tab3Layout` has its own `Annex` `JPanel` (inherited from `Tab3`), which it is modifying and adding components to, while `Tab3` class is inserting its `Annex`, which is initialized via `new JPanel()` and you do nothing else with it. `Tab3Layout` class never even touches `Annex` panel you intialize and add in `Tab3` .

```
public class Tab3 extends JPanel {
JPanel Annex = new JPanel(); // <----- this, an empty JPanel
//A Bunch of Labels and Buttons

public Tab3(){
//ActionListeners for the Buttons
this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
this.add(Annex,BorderLayout.WEST); // <----- is inserted here
this.add(Bsp,BorderLayout.EAST);
}}
```

You will get an error if you delete `new JPanel()`, which will illustrate that both classes are doing work on **different** objects, which just happen to be named the same. You need to pass all components/panels you want to appear in `Tab3` to `Tab3Layout` to modify, then you can retrieve them later with `getters`. Another way would be to create `AnnexPanel` class, which itself would be extending JPanel class. It would set its own layout, components etc. and be able to be added directly. Following [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) would be best, if your classes grow in size. If it's 200+ lines of code, you should consider refactoring it. If you will allow your class to grow like 3000+ lines of code, you will have a bad time. Try to forsee where you can create new class/method in early stages of development. See [KISS principle](http://principles-wiki.net/principles:keep_it_simple_stupid) .

Well..I would split those in different way.

My Tab3Layout class. Annex panel is `injected via constructor`, you can set a `setter` for that, but remember to not call `createAnnex()` before injection. Anyway, compiler will make you remember.

```
public final class Tab3Layout {

    private JPanel Annex;
    JPanel Annex1; //just to avoid compiler error
    private GridBagLayout gridBagLayout;
    private GridBagConstraints co1;

    public Tab3Layout(JPanel Annex) {
        this.Annex = Annex;
        this.gridBagLayout = new GridBagLayout();
        this.co1 = new GridBagConstraints();
    }

    public void createAnnex() {
        this.Annex.setLayout(gridBagLayout);

        this.co1.gridx = 0;
        this.co1.gridy = 0;
        this.co1.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;
        this.co1.weighty = 1.0;

        this.Annex.add(Annex1, co1);
    }

    public JPanel getAnnex() {
        return this.Annex;
    }
}
```

And then the Tab3 class:

```
public class Tab3 extends JPanel {

    JPanel Annex;
    Tab3Layout tab3Layout;

    public Tab3() {
        super();
        this.Annex = new JPanel();

        this.tab3Layout = new Tab3Layout(Annex);
        this.tab3Layout.createAnnex();

        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        this.add(tab3Layout.getAnnex(), BorderLayout.WEST);
        this.add(new JPanel(), BorderLayout.EAST);
    }
}
```

Look at my [GridBagManager](https://github.com/bartlsntsk/GridBagManager) repo, it can give you an idea how to set layout with another class.

You can also extend Tab3Layout with JPanel. And remember to set `anchor` and `fill` with GridBagConstraints.

And [Java naming convention](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-naming-conventions).

```
JPanel Annex = new JPanel();
GridBagConstraints co1 = new GridBagConstraints();
```

to

```
JPanel annexPanel = new JPanel();
GridBagConstraints gridBagConstraints = new GridBagConstraints();
```

Personally I use `gbc` for `GridBagConstraints` object, as you will see in my repo I mentioned above.

Edit:
I think you should split your implementation into couple of smaller classes. That would be professional aproach. Refactor your code. For starters you can make every panel its own class extending `JPanel` (like i suggested with `AnnexPanel` class).

Edit2: `createAnnex()` can return JPanel type, reducing your boilerplate code, your call then would be as follows:

```
this.add(Tab3Layout.createAnnex(), co1);
```

instead of

```
Tab3Layout.createAnnex();
this.add(Tab3Layout.getAnnex(), co1);
```

Maybe even take `createAnnex()` to constructor (assuming class extends `JPanel`) if it's a singleton.